# Incorporating an if statement into a nested For loop

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, nested-loops, rvest

I would be so grateful for any advice. Im trying to scrape a forum using a nested for loop and if statement to capture all comments and replies. I have a feeling its the indentation but cant figure it out. Im looping through a list of Url's, then looping through the pages of each url, and then using an if statement to break if a 'next page' button is missing. Any advice would be so gratefully appreciated

```
df_comments <- tibble()

for (j in df_iva$url) {
  for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 100000, by = 1)){
    link = paste0(j, "/p", i)
    page = read_html(page)
    Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=1.29, max=4.89))
    
    post_title <- j %>% str_remove('https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/discussion/') %>% str_remove('p*')
    user <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//a[@class="Username js-userCard"]') %>% html_attr('data-userid')
    date_time <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="DataBox DataBox-Comments"]//div[@class="Meta RecordMeta"]//span[@class="MItem DateCreated"]//a//time') %>% html_attr('datetime') %>%  ymd_hms()
    
    df_comments = rbind(df_comments, tibble(post_title, user, date_time))
    
    if (page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="P PagerWrap"]//a[@class="Next"]') %>% html_attr('rel') == "next") {
      print(link)
    }
    else 
      {
        print("finished")
        break
      }
  }
  print(paste0("#####     ", j, "     ####"))
  Sys.sleep(runif(1, min=3.29, max=12.89))
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Are you getting an error? Or is the code not doing what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little hard to tell what exactly the problem without a reproducible error, but `else` statements should appear on the same line as the closing `}` of the related `if` statement. In your case, I'd suggest:

```
if (page %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="P PagerWrap"]//a[@class="Next"]') %>% html_attr('rel') == "next") {
  print(link)
} else {
  print("finished")
  break
}
```